# Browser downloads file instead of displaying it

Tags: header, download, http-headers, readfile

I am using php readfile to send a file to the browser. Its is an image file. Howver the browser downloads it, instead of displaying it.
This is the response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2013 14:11:46 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.18-nmm1
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.jpg
Content-Length: 20599
Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=binary
```

Why doesnt it display?

Answer (score 2):

The bad guy is this line:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.jpg
```

Try to remove it in order to show the image in the browser.

Alternatively, use a small html file, as this is the way a browser is supposed to work ;)